# Need help in setting up dev environment & running unit tests for rethinkdb server

Tags: c++, unit-testing, rethinkdb

I am new to rethinkdb and want to setup development environment (particularly rethindb server) on my Ubuntu-20 box.

I was able to build the source, thanks to very concise README!

I want to run unit tests & I am struggling there.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks

I could not find the instructions, hence I peeped into Github Actions file (btw I am not very familiar to Github actions) & ran the following  command:

```
test/run --verbose --jobs "${MAX_JOBS}" -H unit
```

I get an error:

```
ile "test/run", line 33, in load_tests
    execfile(full_path, {"__builtins__": __builtins__, "generate_test": generate_test(tree)})
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

> BTW: I am using `python-3`

Comment: `execfile` [was removed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Make sure to get the right version for your system - rethinkdb is supported from Ubuntu 14, but their installation instructions are claimed to be tested from 20+.

Comment: Thanks @Lodinn, for your reply!

I tried to run with ```python 2.7```, but got some other error.

Would appreciate if someone could point me to instructions for running unit tests locally (on Ubuntu-20). I tried running [this unit-test pipeline step](https://github.com/manojphatak/rethinkdb/blob/v2.4.x/.github/workflows/build.yml#L78), but may be I am missing some setup, as I am not conversant with GitHub Actions.

(I am referring only to rethinkdb-server & am able to build it locally.)